# php dynamic dropdown not holding value after submission

Tags: php, mysql, dropdown

I am trying to build php dynamic dropdowns for searching purpose. For example - search by min price and max price.  Although it shows the right results, the dropdowns do not hold the POST values. Here is my code

```
<div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" name="minprice" id="minprice">
        <option value="">--Min Price--</option>
            <?php
                $args=array(':type' => 'general');
                $sql='SELECT DISTINCT price FROM cars  WHERE cartype=:type AND  price !=" "';
                $stmt=$pdo->prepare($sql);
                $stmt->execute($args);
                while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                    echo '<option value="'.$row['price'].'"'.($row['price']==$_POST['price'] ? '  selected="selected"' : '').'>'.$row['price'].'</option>';
                } 
            ?>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" name="maxprice" id="maxprice">
        <option value="">--Max Price--</option>
            <?php
                $args=array(':type' => 'general');
                $sql='SELECT DISTINCT price FROM cars  WHERE cartype=:type AND  price !=" "';
                $stmt=$pdo->prepare($sql);
                $stmt->execute($args);
                while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                    echo '<option value="'.$row['price'].'"'.($row['price']==$_POST['price'] ? '  selected="selected"' : '').'>'.$row['price'].'</option>';
                } 
            ?>
    </select>
</div>

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
   ........
   .......
    $minprice= $_POST['minprice'];
    $maxprice= $_POST['maxprice'];
    $stmt=$pdo->query("SELECT * FROM cars  WHERE cartype='general' 
        ............
        ...................
        AND price >= '".$minprice."'
        AND price <= '".$maxprice."'
        ");
        while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            {
                include 'carlist.php';
            }
}else{.....}
```

Comment: Do you mean that when you submit the form it gets the right data from the database but the dropdowns do not repopulate with the values the user selected

Comment: thanks @RiggsFolly.  yes. for example, if searched by min price as 500, after submission, the min price dropdown should show 500.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are just using the wrong names for the $_POST values

The select is called `minprice` and `maxprice` and you are testing against `$_POST['price']` which does not exist.

```
<select class="form-control" name="minprice" id="minprice">
    <option value="">--Min Price--</option>
        <?php
            $args=array(':type' => 'general');
            $sql='SELECT DISTINCT price FROM cars  WHERE cartype=:type AND  price !=" "';
            $stmt=$pdo->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute($args);
            while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                echo '<option value="'.$row['price'].'"'.($row['price']==$_POST['minprice'] ? '  selected="selected"' : '').'>'.$row['price'].'</option>';
    //      The correction is here                                              ^^^^^^^
    ?>
</select>
```

And of course the same issue with maxprice dropdown

> To get errors out of PHP even in a LIVE environment add these 4 lines to the top of any `MYSQLI_` based script you want to debug
> `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`.
> This will force any `MYSQLI_` errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser as well as normal PHP errors.

Answer (score 0):

Your presented form fields are named `minprice` and `maxprice`.  Unless you are hiding simthing from us, there is no field named `price`.

Fir this reason, when you call `$_POST['price']`, that variable will trigger a warning stating that you are trying to access an undeclared variable.

It is also possible that the appropriate `$_POST` vatiable will simply not yet be declared because on the initial page load there has been no submission yet.

To fix your code, use the "null coalescing operator" and reference the correct `$_POST` keys.

```
$selectedMin = $_POST['minprice'] ?? null;
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo '<option' . ($row['price'] == $selectedMin ? ' selected' : '') . '>' . $row['price'] . '</option>';
}
```

And repeat for the maxprice.

Notice that I am not declaring the `value` attribute in the option tags.  This is because there is zero benefit in repeating the text value of the option.  Everything will work exactly the same and any javascripting will work identically without the redundant `value` declaration.

---

A broader review:

Make as few trips as possible to the database and certainly don't repeat a query. Cache the resultset in a variable so that you can use it more than once.

Your two form fields are virtually identical, so create the html markup in a loop.

There is no risk of injection with your query, so you don't need a prepared statement.

Rewritten code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/SW3el))

```
$prices = $pdo->query("SELECT DISTINCT price FROM cars WHERE cartype = 'general' AND price != ' '")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);

foreach (['min', 'max'] as $key) {
    $selectedPrice = $_POST[$key . 'price'] ?? '';
    $options = [];
    foreach ($prices as $price) {
        $options[] = sprintf(
            '<option%s>%s</option>',
            $price == $selectedPrice ? ' selected' : '', // 1st %s
            $price                                       // 2nd %s
        );
    }
    printf(
        '<div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control" name="%1$sprice" id="%1$sprice">
                <option value="">--%2$s Price--</option>
                %3$s
            </select>
        </div>
        ',
        $key,                      // represented by %1$s
        ucfirst($key),             // represented by %2$s
        implode(PHP_EOL, $options) // represented by %3$s
    );
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help. yes you are right. I have edited my code and it works fine now

Comment: @S.N.Alam You will need to learn how to accept a best answer on Stack Overflow.  https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/352329

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if this answers your question, but you know that once the page is 'posted' the information from the pull-down menu is lost unless you: (i) store it in a PhP $_SESSION variable; or (ii) otherwise save the info you want to a database or a .txt file.

So, if what you are trying to do is save the user's choice after POST, then one solution would be to create two $_SESSION variables which is how you store information across PhP page refreshes or across different pages.

Comment: thanks @Rasputin for your help. I have some more fields on the form and with my current coding the other fields are holding the POST values. Only these two fields are not holding the POST values.